Are specific mining hardware questions topcial?
Are specific questions about miner setups etc topical eg.

Will x miner work with x pcu
Will x miner hardware work with x software


Yes, because it is factually answerable, and the answer will stay the same, such questions can be a good fit. 
However, such questions may be answerable by a simple websearch, so it would probably make sense to ask only if it is harder to determine than that and then explain what previous research has been done, and that it was unsuccessful.

Thanks! I have had a rather hard time digging the BTC forums and such to find the info I need, and it is often not there...
